# Mark as succes past for a new task in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I trying to implement an automatic way of setting the state of new task added to an existing dag to success. I can do this manually using the web interface with the option Mark success and selecting past. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate on your situation?

Comment: Yes, when you add a new task to an existing dag, the task is added with empty state for all the dag past. When deploying and specially if the new task depends on past, I need to manually set to success the past for the task in order to enable the execution. This can be done using the web interface button 'Mark success' and selecting the option past. The issue is for example when deploying several new tasks, I'd like to avoid the manual work

Comment: did you find your solution to this? if so pls share.